# android: generic imageview (or any other view) inside a custom relativeLayout(or...)

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I know it may seem a little dumb!
correct me if I'm thinking wrong.

I made a custom relativeLayout which has some sort of a dynamic behavior depended on screen size. and I need to add an imageView inside this layout which inherits its dimensions just like its parent.

I want to know if there's a way that I can implement an imageview within my custom layout class so that everytime I add it in a layout, the imageview comes along in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can add any `View` you want automatically within the custom `RelativeLayout`. I see a few different approaches you could take.
**1-** Create an xml layout for the content of your custom `RelativeLayout`, you could also use a `<merge>` as root tag if you have many views:

```
public class CustomRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private ImageView imageView;

    public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflate(context, R.layout.custom_relative_layout, this);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    }
}
```

custom_relative_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/image_view"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**2-** create the `View` programmatically

```
public class CustomRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private ImageView imageView;

    public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        addView(imageView);
    }
}
```

**3-** create an xml with your `CustomRelativeLayout` and any child `View` in it, than include it in other layouts with `<include>`. Get a reference of the children `View`s in `onFinishInflate()`

```
public class CustomRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    }
}
```

custom_relative_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.CustomRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</com.example.CustomRelativeLayout>
```

and use it somewhere else with

```
<include layout="@layout/custom_relative_layout"/>
```

Comment: thanks buddy. I wasn't pretty familiar with custom views. this helped me so much.